# Does SQL Server support statistics on geometry column?

Tags: sql-server, spatial-query, spatial-index

I have a query on spatial data. In execution plan I see warnings, that geo-column does not have statistics.

[image]

I have index on this column, but I can't create statistics.

1. Does SQL Server support statistics on geometry column?
2. How can I avoid this warning?

Answer (score 0):

In turn:

1. It doesn't appear that SQL Server supports statistics on geometry/geography columns. Here's a simple demonstration:

   create table #foo (g geometry);
   create statistics foo_g on #foo (g);

When I run this, I get the following error:

> Msg 1978, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Column 'g' in table '#foo' is of a
>   type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index or
>   statistics.

2. I don't think you do. I wish the optimizer was smart enough to say "that column will never have statistics (as a natural consequence of the above) and not gripe about it. But alas, it is the optimizer that Gotham *has*, not the optimizer Gotham *deserves*.

Comment: In query plan I see that server expects 40000000 rows, but it gets only 481 :) And, I think, it can cause problems

Comment: Indeed. Without knowing more about you query (and the spatial index), it's hard for me to say what can be done about it without platitudes.

Answer (score 0):

It supports bounding boxes and grid levels instead of statistics.

If you tilt your head a little, you will realize a bounding box is effectively a custom statistics histogram that controls what tiny box your geometric points (object) fits into.  The grid levels then control the depth of the search into that bounding box.